# NIFI XML converting

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

I have a problem with converting flowfile to xml.
So i using ConvertRecord processor to convert Avro in to XML, but this processor add some text
This is original xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<FDX> ... <FDX>
```

But after nifi processing it reforming to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nifiRecord><atribute>     
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
        <FDX> ... <FDX>
</nifiRecord></atribute>
```

So, my question is: How i can remove this add text from added text from file for further recording?

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the anwser.
Information above atribute's tag is just for nifi. It is not part of transformed data.
You can transfor this information in to JSON(for example) and added information in previous processor will be removed. So don't worry about this.